# What events trigger low_stock_date to be updated?

Tags: inventory, out-of-stock, cataloginventory

What events trigger cataloginventory_stock_item.low_stock_date?  In our db most of the products have the same exact timestamp, and it's only 4 days ago, despite a lot of these products being out of stock for a long time.

Comment: X-Ref: [cataloginventory_stock_item.low_stock_date?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/90455/4115) - 18 Nov 2015