# cataloginventory_stock_item.low_stock_date?

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, out-of-stock, stock-status, cataloginventory

Table `cataloginventory_stock_item` column `low_stock_date` In our db
most of the products have the same exact timestamp. how the event trigger for low stock and how to get the exact date. Actually lot of these products being out of stock for a long time.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

`low_stock_date` is set in two places:

1. when saving a stock item: [Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php#L733-L735)
2. when importing products: [Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L1628-L1631)

If you did not change the stock of those items manually using a mass action, the products were probably imported at the same time.